# How can I rename each column of a table?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a table with X columns, and I want to rename each with its own name.

I want to rename the first column using the string on A1, the second with the string on B1, and so on.

[image]

I tried using:
`ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Name, RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R2C1:R70C1"`

But I want to replace the `R2C1:R70C1` to something like `R2CA:R70CA` where A's value goes up for each column. And also replace `Sheet1` with `ActiveSheet.Name`

Any suggestions?

Note: No, the table isn't an object, so `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet").ListObjects("Table").ListColumns("Column name").Name = "New column name"` doesn't work.

Note 2: I'm using Excel 2013

Comment: Suggestion - [how to find the last used cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba).

Comment: 1. To concatenate strings in VBA, use the `&` operator. 2. To have a range give you its address, use the `.Address` property. To create a range from variable column and row indexes, use `.Cells` along with `Resize`, `Offset` and other methods. e.g. `RefersToR1C1:="=" & ActiveSheet.Columns(X).Cells(2, 1).Resize(69).Address(External:=True)` where `X` is your column variable.

Comment: What do you mean when you say *"string on A1"*? A1 is blank. Do you mean that you want to add names like the headers, e.g. `Days`, `Dates`... etc? Don't you need dynamic rows, too, or are they fixed from `2` to `70`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant A2. I didn't create a dynamic table, I'm just using copied and pasted columns from another document, but they are limited from 2 to 70, some can have less rows, but the standard is 69 rows.

Answer (score 0):

### Add Name For Each Column

```vb
Sub AddNames()
    
    Const FirstCol As String = "A"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const LastRow As Long = 70
    
    With ActiveSheet

        Dim wsName As String: wsName = .Name

        Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = .Cells(FirstRow, FirstCol)
        Dim rg As Range
        Set rg = .Range(fCell, .Cells(FirstRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) _
            .Resize(LastRow - FirstRow + 1)

        Dim crg As Range, ErrNumber As Long, nmName As String

        For Each crg In rg.Columns

            nmName = CStr(crg.Cells(1).Value)

            On Error Resume Next
                .Names.Add nmName, "'" & wsName & "'!" & crg.Address
                ErrNumber = Err.Number
            On Error GoTo 0

            If ErrNumber <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Could not add name """ & nmName & """.", vbCritical
                ErrNumber = 0
            End If

        Next crg

    End With
        
    MsgBox "Names added.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

- If you want the ranges of only the data (no headers), use the following:

```vb
Sub AddNamesData()
    
    Const FirstCol As String = "A"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const LastRow As Long = 70
    
    With ActiveSheet
        
        Dim wsName As String: wsName = .Name
        
        Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = .Cells(FirstRow, FirstCol)
        Dim rg As Range
        Set rg = .Range(fCell, .Cells(FirstRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) _
            .Resize(LastRow - FirstRow + 1)
        
        Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = rg.Rows(1)
        Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        
        Dim hCell As Range, c As Long, ErrNumber As Long, nmName As String
        
        For Each hCell In hrg.Cells
            
            c = c + 1
            nmName = CStr(hCell.Value)
            
            On Error Resume Next
                .Names.Add nmName, "'" & wsName & "'!" & drg.Columns(c).Address
                ErrNumber = Err.Number
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            If ErrNumber <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Could not add name """ & nmName & """.", vbCritical
                ErrNumber = 0
            End If
        
        Next hCell
    
    End With
        
    MsgBox "Names added.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: It went through every string correctly, but it didn't name any column https://imgur.com/kw2AEKw